# How to convert path to Uri in android?

Tags: android, path, uri

How to convert path to uri in android? And i want also how to create a thumbnail of pdf file in android? And How to i can upload a pdf file on server.

using

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_PDF_REQUEST);
```

Its use to throw FileNotFoundException Exception and ENOENT Exception

Comment: This is not a good practice to gather several unrelated questions. You better off separating each one into a different post.

Answer (score 0):

Use Uri.parse() or Uri.fromFile()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri

Answer (score 0):

one line code:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(path);
```

Comment: i'll try this method also.But not get a exact Uri

Comment: please use file provider to get absolute file path of audio,video,image and document

Answer (score 0):

Uri.fromFile(strPath) it returned Uri of string path